# How do you filter rows in a pandas dataframe conditional on columns existing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing counts of two things, which I've put in columns `numA` and `numB`. I want to find the rows where `numA < x` and `numB < y`, which can be done like so:

```
filtered_df = df[(df.numA < x) & (df.numB < y)]
```

This works when both `numA` and `numB` are present. However *neither column is guaranteed to appear in the dataframe*. If only one column exists, I would still like to filter the rows based on it. This could be easily coded with something along the lines of

```
if "numA" in df.columns:
    filtered_df = df[df.numA < x]
if "numB" in df.columns:
    filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_df.numB < y]
```

But this seems very inefficient, especially since in reality I have 9 columns like this, and each of these requires the same check. Is there a way to achieve the same thing but with code that is more readable, easier to maintain and less tedious to write out?

Comment: You could fill in the missing entries with a default value (that is higher than your check value and therefore will evaluate to True) - [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna). Use a value that wouldn't occur and/or use a copy of the data so the the fact there are missing entries doesn't get permanently wiped.

Comment: Theoretically you could chain operators together with [isnull()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html). Not at my desk at the moment to test in full, hence a comment not an answer. e.g. (df.numA < x) | (df.numA.isnull())

Comment: @Alan there are no null values, the _entire columns_ are potentially absent in the dataframe. For some context: I begin with a large dataframe containing more columns, and then delete some of the columns, potentially removing `numA` and `numB` along the way depending on certain conditions. So if `numA` isn't present then `df.numA.isnull()` returns an error: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'numA'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an all-or-nothing type comparison I think a fairly easy way is to use set comparisons:

```
if(set(list_of_cols_to_check).issubset(df.columns)):
    filtered_df = df[(df.numA < x) & ... & (df.numB < y)]
```

If you want to perform comparisons for all that do exist it gets a bit more complicated. It is not very different than what you have, but I'd probably do it as follows:

```
filter = (df.index >= 0) #always true
filter = filter & (df.numA < 4)  if 'numA' in df else filter
filter = filter & (df.numB < 2)  if 'numB' in df else filter
filter = filter & (df.numC < 1)  if 'numC' in df else filter
df[filter]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simpler solution if you're not sure if the columns will be there when you filter for them:

```py
df.loc[:,df.column.isin(["numA", "numB", "numC"])]
```

- `isin()` will return an array of booleans if the column exists
- `.loc[]` takes index and column as arguments
- the `:` means all indices
- the second argument is the array of columns as booleans